# Prime Number and Block Length in Karp Rabin

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, hash, rabin-karp

I found a rabin karp code from [that](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-3-rabin-karp-algorithm/) site and changed to try. Changed code is below. You can see words and their hash values in hashtable.txt. for below example hashtable.txt seems right.

But when I changed M (block length) to 150 I am getting wrong results. For example in hashtable.txt first line and 6th line must be same but their hash values are different.

Or when I changed q (prime number) to 683303 it's getting wrong results too.

What's the relation between prime number and block length in rabin karp algorithm, and what's reason of wrong results?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
// d is the number of characters in input alphabet
#define d 256 
int M = 80;
/*  
txt  -> text
q    -> A prime number
*/
using namespace std;

void writeTable(char *txt, int q)
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("hashtable.txt");
int N = strlen(txt);
int i, j;
int t = 0; // hash value for txt
int h = 1;

// The value of h would be "pow(d, M-1)%q"
for (i = 0; i < M-1; i++)
    h = (h*d)%q;

// Calculate the hash value of pattern and first window of text
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    t = (d*t + txt[i])%q;
}

// Slide the pattern over text one by one 
for (i = 0; i <= N - M; i++)
{
    myfile << t <<" ";
    for (long z = i; z < M+i; z++){myfile<<txt[z];}myfile<<"\n";

    // Calulate hash value for next window of text: Remove leading digit, 
    // add trailing digit           
    if ( i < N-M )
    {
        t = (d*(t - txt[i]*h) + txt[i+M])%q;

        // We might get negative value of t, converting it to positive
        if(t < 0) 
          t = (t + q); 
    }
}

myfile.close();
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    char *txt ="abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde";

int q = 683303;  // A prime number

writeTable(txt, q);

printf("finish");
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The computation

```
t = (d*(t - txt[i]*h) + txt[i+M])%q;
```

can overflow. The maximal value of `txt[i]` is `d-1`, and `h` can be as large as `q-1`. So if `(q-1)*(d-1)*d > INT_MAX`, there is the possibility of integer overflow. That limits the size of the prime that can be safely chosen to `INT_MAX/(d*(d-1)) + 1`.

If `q` is larger than that, that poses restrictions on the admissible values for `M`, namely `M` must be such that

```
h <= INT_MAX/(d*(d-1))
```

to safely prevent overflow.

With `q = 683303` and `M = 80`, you get `h = 182084`, and

```
h*d*(d-1) = 182084 * 256 * 255 = 11886443520
```

is larger than `INT_MAX` if `int` is 32 bits wide as it usually is.

If your `int`s are 32 bits wide, you have overflow for the example from the beginning, because `h*256*97 = 4521509888 > 2147483647`.

Comment: I tried it for d=256 M=40 q=139907 so h= 53941. but INT_MAX/(d*(d-1))=32896 . after all it's worked correctly. h isn't lesser then 32896 for that example it should give me wrong result. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Apart from the fact that even after overflow you could get a correct result by pure chance (don't expect to live to see that, though), in your example text, if I haven't overlooked a character, and assuming ASCII compatible encoding (no idea about EBCDIC's code numbers), the largest occurring value is 101 - for `'e'` - so the maximal product you actually get in that is `53941*256*101 = 1394698496`, which is smaller than `2^31-1`. With these values of `q` and `M` (hence `h`), you don't get overflow if the entire input is ASCII (i.e. `< 128`).

Answer (score 1):

The "block length" is the length of the pattern. Since you don't have any pattern in your code, the number 150 is meaningless, unless that's the actual length of the pattern that you intend to use.

The values of hashes must depend on the data being hashed and on the amount of it. So, hashes of "abcde", "abcd", "abc" are likely to be all different.

In this algorithm you avoid unnecessary comparing of the pattern to a same-length portion of the text by first comparing the hashes of both.

If the hashes are different, you know the two sequences of characters are different and there's no match and so you can move on to the next position in the text and repeat the procedure.

If the hashes match, you have a potential match of the two character sequences and then you compare them to see if there's a real match.

This is the main idea of the algorithm and this is what makes it faster than naïve implementations of substring search.

The purpose of dividing by a prime number when calculating the hashes is to try to get a more uniform distribution of hash values. If you choose a very big prime number, it's not going to have much if any effect. If you choose a very small prime number, you reduce the total number of hash values and are increasing the odds of hash matches and therefore the odds of doing unnecessary substring comparison.

Comment: it's not meaningless. That code is written for see whether hashes are right or not. That't not my entire project.

Comment: I did write the `unless ...` clause.